# Scan characters until enter key

Tags: c, arrays, linux, shell

I'm doing a UNIX shell in C language.
All works fine but when I press ENTER without introduce any character before, there's a newline when the prompt should be shown.

This is my loop to receive the commands.
The '\n' char is not in 'text' array variable when it's pressed first.

```
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i=0, final=FALSE, background=FALSE;
    char text[TAM_MAX];

    while (final == FALSE) {
        printf(PROMPT); 
        scanf("\n%[^\n]", text); // Scan until enter is pressed
        background = FALSE; 

        for(i=0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) { 
            if (text[i] == '&') { 
            text[i] = '\0';
            background = TRUE; // & > background instruction
        }
    }

    if (isFinal(text) == TRUE) break; // 'exit' was introduced
    executeCommand(text, background);
}
```

Comment: there should be a compiler warning ``scanf is difficult``

Comment: [man scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) is a good place to start. [google is also a good place to start](https://www.google.fr/search?q=C+read+from+stdin+until+return)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the first \n in the string-it will cause not only newlines (consecutive whitespace) to be read in, but all CONSECUTIVE whitespace, "and it (scanf) **may need to read ANOTHER line before it can find that FIRST non-whitespace character**."

For This code:

```
scanf("\n%[^\n]", text); // Scan until enter is pressed
```

If ONLY a newline is entered first, it will be dropped.

But the first \n in this code will also cause ANY number of consecutive white space characters to be read in - not just one.

It is possible scanf is expecting to read and drop any possible
additional whitespace characters because of the first \n.  From the 
documentation (SEE BELOW):

REFERENCE #1:

```
http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html

"The \n in "%d\n" therefore causes scanf to read characters until 
it finds a non-whitespace character, and it may need to read another 
line before it can find that non-whitespace character."
```

REFERENCE #2:

```
http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html

"Perhaps surprisingly, \n in a scanf format string does not mean to 
expect a newline, but rather to read and DISCARD characters <B>as 
long as each is a whitespace character</B>. (In fact, ANY 
whitespace character in a scanf format string means to read and 
discard whitespace characters."
```

FROM THE DOCUMENTATION:

```
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/
```

Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%): Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread.

Format specifiers: A sequence formed by an initial percentage sign (%) indicates a format specifier, which is used to specify the type and format of the data to be retrieved from the stream and stored into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.